# Intellij how to format method signature and javadoc comment multi-line format?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, code-formatting

Intellij java editor code format:

```
/**
 * @param nameOfAParameterVeryLong this is a very long multiple line comment,
 *                                 next line starts from beginning.
 */
public void fooVeryLongMethodName(Integer parameter1, Integer parameter2,
                                  String parameter3, String parameter4) {
    ... 
}
```

How to format the above as the following:

```
/**
 * @param nameOfAParameterVeryLong this is a very long multiple line comment,
 * next line starts from beginning.
 */
public void fooVeryLongMethodName(Integer parameter1, Integer parameter2,
        String parameter3, String parameter4) {
    ... 
}
```

Do not align the parameters and comment multi-lines. Is there any settings for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following settings:

[image: JavaDoc settings]

Comment: See wrapping an braces.